# Can I use Hoomd-Blue to easily measure end to end distance of a simulated polymer?

Tags: python

I am using **Hoomd-blue** to run some simulations with strings of particles. Does anybody know if there is a more convenient function I can use to measure an average end to end distance of the polymers without printing out the `[x,y,z]` coordinates and writing a script from scratch to calculate the distance?

Answer (score 1):

Hoomd-blue doesn't offer this functionality but it can done by periodically dumping and gsd file and then looping over the frames + atoms to calculate the distance. If you have some reason where you need a more in-situ method, you could either use a [python callback](https://hoomd-blue.readthedocs.io/en/stable/module-hoomd-analyze.html#hoomd.analyze.callback) which will be slow OR write a plugin in C++.